# using axspreadsheet in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having an awful time with axspreadsheet for vb.net 2008. The simplest example is I just add the control to the form. It compiles on one computer, but it doesn't compile on any other computer. I may be missing a reference or a prerequisite but I have searched for about 10 hours, and I have not gotten any insight into this. Thank you so much for any help.

This is the error that I get when I try to run it:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is:class not registered (exception from HRESULT:080040154 (regdb_e_classnotreg))

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it seems you are missing a COM component.

I guess, you should try to re-install the component, start a fresh app & drop the control on the form to see if that works (on the machine, where it is not working).

Comment: tried that already. i've tried this on 3 different machines. it works only on one machine even though i have vb.net 2008 installed on another one

Comment: See if the COM component is registered? Did you install the component as an Admin?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you copy-paste the dll which you imported to your project and there is no any installed Excel on your computer. You should install Excel before add reference AxSpreadSheet component or register that component as COM component. But I'm sorry I don't know how to register.

Answer (score 0):

Register this AxInterop.OWC11.dll on each machine where your using the axspreadsheet control.